# Is there a faster way of looping through a set and replacing MWE in a sentence? - Python

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, set, nlp

The task is to group expressions that are made up of multiple words (aka `Multi-Word Expressions`).

Given a dictionary of MWE, I need to add dashes to the input sentences where MWE are detected, e.g.

```
**Input:** i have got an ace of diamonds in my wet suit .
**Output:** i have got an ace-of-diamonds in my wet-suit .
```

Currently I looped through the sorted dictionary and see whether the MWE appears in the sentence and replace them whenever it appears. But there's a lot of wasted iterations.

Is there a better way of doing so? One solution is to produce all possible n-grams 1st, i.e. `chunker2()`

```
import re, time
mwe_list =set([i.strip() for i in codecs.open( \
            "wn-mwe-en.dic","r","utf8").readlines()])

def chunker(sentence):
  for item in mwe_list:
    if item or item.replace("-", " ") in sentence:
      #print item
      mwe_item =  '-'.join(item.split(" "))
      r=re.compile(re.escape(mwe_item).replace('\\-','[- ]'))
      sentence=re.sub(r,mwe_item,sentence)    
  return sentence

def chunker2(sentence):
    nodes = []
    tokens = sentence.split(" ")
    for i in range(0,len(tokens)):
        for j in range(i,len(tokens)):
            nodes.append(" ".join(tokens[i:j]))
    n = sorted(set([i for i in nodes if not "" and len(i.split(" ")) > 1]))

    intersect = mwe_list.intersection(n)

    for i in intersect:
        print i
        sentence = sentence.replace(i, i.replace(" ", "-"))

    return sentence

s = "i have got an ace of diamonds in my wet suit ."

time.clock()
print chunker(s)
print time.clock()

time.clock()
print chunker2(s)
print time.clock()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd try doing it like this:

- For each sentence, construct a set of n-grams up to a given length (the longest MWE in your list).
- Now, just do `mwe_nmgrams.intersection(sentence_ngrams)` and search/replace them.

You won't have to waste time by iterating over all of the items in your original set.

---

Here's a slightly faster version of `chunker2`:

```
def chunker3(sentence):
    tokens = sentence.split(' ')
    len_tokens = len(tokens)
    nodes = set()

    for i in xrange(0, len_tokens):
        for j in xrange(i, len_tokens):
            chunks = tokens[i:j]

            if len(chunks) > 1:
                nodes.add(' '.join(chunks))

    intersect = mwe_list.intersection(n)

    for i in intersect:
        print i
        sentence = sentence.replace(i, i.replace(' ', '-'))

    return sentence
```

Comment: Yep that's tremendously faster, 11.04 secs to 0.74 seconds for 13 word sentences. But that'll be a lot slower on the longer sentences, any recommendations to trim the ngrams?

Comment: @2er0: You could take into account the longest MWE and just make sure that the inner `for` loop goes from `i` to `min(i + longest_possible_ngram, len_tokens)`. That should speed it up a little bit. Take a look at my answer once more. I added some slight changes that should make your code a bit faster.

Comment: Thanks! yet that does work faster. Hopefully the server can handle the load of 2,000,000 sentences with 30 - 100 words per sentence =)

Comment: @2er0: No problem. If you're not already using it, take a look at the `multiprocessing` module. That'll give you a *huge* boost.

Comment: Nice. Don't forget to replace any hyphens in the dic or sentence with spaces first, so your chunks split and match where they should.

Answer (score 2):

First, a 2x improvement: Because you are replacing the MWEs with hyphenated versions, you can pre-process the dictionary (wn-mwe-en.dic) to eliminate all hyphens from the MWEs in the set, eliminating one string comparison. If you allow hyphens within the sentence, then you'll have to pre-process it as well, presumably online, for a minor penalty. This should cut your runtime in half.

Next, a minor improvement: Immutable tuples are generally faster for iteration rather than a set or list (which are mutable and the iterator has to check for movement of elements in memory with each step). The set() conversion will eliminate duplicates, as you intend. The tuple bit will firm it up in memory allowing low level iteration optimizations by the python interpreter and its compiled libs.

Finally, you should probably parse both the sentence and the MWEs into words or tokens before doing all your comparisons, this would cut down on the # of string comparisons required by the average length of your words (4x if your words are 4 characters long on average). You'd also be able to nest another loop to search for the first word in the MWE as an anchor for all MWEs that share that first word, reducing the length of the string comparisons required. But I'll leave this lion's share for you experimentation on real data. And depending on the intepreter vs. compiled lib efficiency, doing all this splitting nested looping at the python level may actually slow things down.

So here's the result of the first two easy "sure" bets.  Should be 2x faster despite the preprocessing, unless your sentence is very short.

```
mwe_list = set(i.strip() for i in codecs.open("wn-mwe-en.dic", "r", "utf8").readlines())
mwe_list = tuple(mwe.replace('-', ' ').strip() for mwe in mwe_list)
sentence = sentence.replace('-', ' ').strip()

def chunker(sentence):
  for item in mwe_list:
    if item in sentence:
    ...
```

Couldn't find a .dic file on my system or I'd profile it for you.

Comment: I'll be glad to share my dictionary http://pastebin.com/sUt6ePtY , (i couldnt paste more than 500kb). But the dictionary is downloaded extracted and downloaded from http://casta-net.jp/~kuribayashi/multi/wns/eng.zip. Please cite appropriately from the references http://casta-net.jp/~kuribayashi/multi/

Comment: No sweat. Looks like my answer was OBE anyway.